# The percentage is wrong in R histogram plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

In R, I have a dataframe `c` (the content of `c` is at: http://pastebin.com/MzwMc108). Please let me know if there is a better way to share `c`

Then I did

```
d <- as.data.frame(c)
colnames(d) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
ggplot(melt(d), aes (value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "dodge", binwidth = 0.1, aes(y = ..density..)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,0.1), labels = percent) +
  xlab ("Actions") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
  ylab ("Percentage") + scale_fill_grey()
```

The idea is to plot the histogram of A, B, C, D together side by side.

I have a plot

[image: histogram plot]

The Y-axis is completely wrong (the percentage comes up to 300%). Could you give me some suggestions so I can fix my code?

Thanks a lot,

**Update**

The output of `dput(c)` is:

```
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0, 0.222222222222222, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.166666666666667, 0.555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 0.566666666666667, 
0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.555555555555556, 0.133333333333333, 
0.5, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 
1, 0, 0.133333333333333, 0, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.366666666666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.466666666666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.133333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 
0, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 0.416666666666667, 
0, 0, 0.416666666666667, 0.2, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0.25, 0, 
0.375, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0.466666666666667, 
0, 0.5, 0.533333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.833333333333333, 0.0666666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 1, 0.416666666666667, 0.0333333333333333, 
0.111111111111111, 0.666666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 0.133333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.444444444444444, 0.466666666666667, 
0.388888888888889, 0, 1, 0.388888888888889, 0.266666666666667, 
0, 0.5, 0, 0.375, 0.166666666666667, 0.0476190476190476, 0.533333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 0.333333333333333, 0.466666666666667, 
0.133333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.266666666666667, 0.2, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 0.0833333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.4, 0.333333333333333, 0.533333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0, 0.466666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.5, 0.2, 0.277777777777778, 0.416666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.833333333333333, 0.466666666666667, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.533333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.266666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.266666666666667, 0.555555555555556, 0.5, 0, 0.0666666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 
0.2, 0, 0.533333333333333, 0.2, 0.444444444444444, 0.222222222222222, 
0.466666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.133333333333333, 
0, 0.555555555555556, 0, 0.533333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0.555555555555556, 0.444444444444444, 0.466666666666667, 
0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.533333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.1, 0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.2, 0.133333333333333, 
0, 0.133333333333333, 0.533333333333333, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.533333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 
0.444444444444444, 0.5, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 0.222222222222222, 0.666666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 0.555555555555556, 0.166666666666667, 
0.566666666666667, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 
0.444444444444444, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.555555555555556, 
0.133333333333333, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 1, 0, 0.133333333333333, 0, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
0.366666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 
0.466666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.133333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 
0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0, 0.533333333333333, 0.583333333333333, 0.523809523809524, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0.555555555555556, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
1, 0.444444444444444, 1, 0.166666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 
0.0333333333333333, 0.5, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
1, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.533333333333333, 0, 0.5, 
0, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.833333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 
0.583333333333333, 0.583333333333333, 0.4, 0.666666666666667, 
0.533333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.533333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 
0.4, 0.666666666666667, 0.6, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.6, 
0.5, 0.555555555555556, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.583333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.6, 0.333333333333333, 0.611111111111111, 0.75, 0.333333333333333, 
0.5, 0.944444444444445, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 
0.5, 0.533333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
1, 0.666666666666667, 0.555555555555556, 0.533333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.6, 0, 0.2, 0.333333333333333, 0.555555555555556, 0.133333333333333, 
0.166666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.476190476190476, 0.666666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.444444444444444, 0.533333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.633333333333333, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.533333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0.833333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.666666666666667, 0.19047619047619, 
0.5, 1, 0.523809523809524, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.533333333333333, 0.476190476190476, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0.5, 
0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 
0.555555555555556, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.133333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0, 0.666666666666667, 
0.533333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.2, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 
0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.533333333333333, 
0.466666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.2, 
0.666666666666667, 0.2, 0.2, 0.466666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.285714285714286, 0.533333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.233333333333333, 
0.766666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 0.476190476190476, 0.4, 
0.466666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.4, 0.416666666666667, 
0.4, 0.466666666666667, 0.4, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
0.5, 0.4, 0.466666666666667, 0.4, 0.5, 0.388888888888889, 0.625, 
0.388888888888889, 0.555555555555556, 0.380952380952381, 0.481481481481481, 
0.476190476190476, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
0.476190476190476, 0.4, 0.375, 0.5, 0.5, 0.380952380952381, 0.366666666666667, 
0.266666666666667, 0.481481481481481, 0.333333333333333, 0.4, 
0.481481481481481, 0.388888888888889, 0.466666666666667, 0.4, 
0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.388888888888889, 0.481481481481481, 
0.5, 0.375, 0.444444444444444, 0.5, 0.388888888888889, 0.466666666666667, 
0.444444444444444, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0, 0.533333333333333, 0.5, 0.4, 0.666666666666667, 0.583333333333333, 
0.266666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.4, 0.566666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.466666666666667, 0, 0.5, 
0.266666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.5, 0.583333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 0.5, 0.25, 0.466666666666667, 
0, 0.133333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.433333333333333, 0.291666666666667, 
0.5, 0.555555555555556, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.583333333333333, 0, 0.533333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.166666666666667, 
0.5, 0.466666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.133333333333333, 
0.111111111111111, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
0.133333333333333, 0, 0.433333333333333, 0.133333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.6, 0.5, 0.6, 0.444444444444444, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.2, 0.222222222222222, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.444444444444444, 
0.166666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.666666666666667, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.5, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.5, 
0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 
0, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.2, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0, 1, 1, 0.555555555555556, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
0.133333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 0.833333333333333, 0.476190476190476, 
0.333333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 0.444444444444444, 1, 0.666666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.277777777777778, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0.333333333333333, 
0.833333333333333, 0.5, 0.533333333333333, 1, 0.0666666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.533333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 
0.466666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.7, 0.666666666666667, 
0.5, 0.333333333333333, 1, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0, 1, 
0.458333333333333, 0.533333333333333, 0.555555555555556, 0.555555555555556, 
0.666666666666667, 1, 0.166666666666667, 0.541666666666667, 0, 
0.444444444444444, 0.166666666666667, 0.583333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.2, 0.833333333333333, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.444444444444444, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.5, 0.142857142857143, 
0.476190476190476, 0.333333333333333, 0.296296296296296, 0.5, 
0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.555555555555556, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0.666666666666667, 
0.208333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0, 0.5, 0.476190476190476, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
0.833333333333333, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.466666666666667, 
0, 0.7, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.476190476190476, 0.666666666666667, 
0.433333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.444444444444444, 
0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.444444444444444, 0.666666666666667, 
0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.833333333333333, 0.583333333333333, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.285714285714286, 0.5, 
0.333333333333333, 0.714285714285714, 0.5, 0.238095238095238, 
0.666666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.4, 
0.333333333333333, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.466666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0.541666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.466666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.4, 0.444444444444444, 
0.523809523809524, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.476190476190476, 
0.533333333333333, 0.533333333333333, 0, 0.541666666666667, 0.566666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.541666666666667, 
0, 0.466666666666667, 0.566666666666667, 0.566666666666667, 0.5, 
0.555555555555556, 0.6, 0.466666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.533333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.541666666666667, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.523809523809524, 0.666666666666667, 
0.566666666666667, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0.444444444444444, 0, 
0.533333333333333, 0.566666666666667, 0.476190476190476, 0.4, 
0.166666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.476190476190476, 0.416666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.444444444444444, 0.5, 
0.533333333333333, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.555555555555556, 
0.555555555555556, 0.444444444444444, 0.466666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.533333333333333, 0.133333333333333, 
0, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0.444444444444444, 0.533333333333333, 
0.444444444444444, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 
0.541666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0.666666666666667, 
0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
1, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
1, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.666666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.5, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 
0.111111111111111, 0.466666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.566666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.0833333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.5, 0.0833333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 0, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
0.444444444444444, 0.0666666666666667, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
0.5, 0.388888888888889, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.133333333333333, 0.888888888888889, 0.666666666666667, 
0.633333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.633333333333333, 
0.555555555555556, 0.333333333333333, 0.611111111111111, 0.666666666666667, 
0.5, 0.555555555555556, 0.533333333333333, 0.5, 0.583333333333333, 
0.555555555555556, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.523809523809524, 
0.555555555555556, 0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.333333333333333, 
0.633333333333333, 0.5, 0.0666666666666667, 0.4, 0.5, 0.166666666666667, 
1, 0.333333333333333, 0.4, 0.444444444444444, 0.533333333333333, 
0.633333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.233333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.266666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.233333333333333, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.233333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0.233333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 
0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.3, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.476190476190476, 0.5, 0.833333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.416666666666667, 0.833333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.4, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.416666666666667, 0.0666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.476190476190476, 
0.666666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 0.476190476190476, 0.666666666666667, 
0.533333333333333, 0.388888888888889, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 
0.333333333333333, 0.416666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.388888888888889, 
0.466666666666667, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.416666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.444444444444444, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
0.466666666666667, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.625, 0.4, 0, 0.333333333333333, 
0.4, 0.416666666666667, 0.5, 0.466666666666667, 0.583333333333333, 
0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.416666666666667, 0, 0.466666666666667, 0.541666666666667, 
0.6, 0.466666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.566666666666667, 
0.466666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.5, 0.533333333333333, 
0.5, 0.466666666666667, 0.5, 0.533333333333333, 0.466666666666667, 
0.5, 0.833333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.541666666666667, 
0, 0.5, 0.541666666666667, 0.125, 0.5, 0.5, 0.555555555555556, 
0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 
0.888888888888889, 0.277777777777778, 0.555555555555556, 0.416666666666667, 
0.444444444444444, 0.277777777777778, 0.416666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.380952380952381, 0.333333333333333, 
0.555555555555556, 0.466666666666667, 0, 0.444444444444444, 0.583333333333333, 
0.166666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.375, 
0.888888888888889, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0.555555555555556, 
0.444444444444444, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 0.4, 0.333333333333333, 
0.375, 0.4, 0.444444444444444, 0.5, 0.555555555555556, 0.333333333333333, 
0.428571428571429, 0.555555555555556, 0.4, 0.6, 0.333333333333333, 
0.444444444444444, 0.6, 0.5, 0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 
0.416666666666667, 0.625, 0.0666666666666667, 0.466666666666667, 
0.444444444444444, 0.523809523809524, 0.25, 0.166666666666667, 
0.6, 0.833333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0, 0.666666666666667, 1), .Dim = c(340L, 
4L))
```

Comment: You can provide `c` right here by pasting the output of `dput(c)`.

Comment: How the vector `percent` looks like? Deleting `labels=percent` in the `scale_y` function should solve the problem.

Comment: This may also help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172311/r-geom-density-values-in-y-axis

Comment: Hi @Jimbou, there is no vector ``percent``, it is a parameter sent to the ggplot2

Comment: Hi @Gopala, I tried to use ``..scaled..`` instead of ``..density..`` and got the error: ``Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'scaled' not found``

Comment: Ok, nevertheless omitting `scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)` should work.

Comment: Hi @Jimbou, when I omit ``scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)``, now Y_axis turned to ``0,1,2,3,4``, but not percentage of histogram.

Comment: @kid_2901 this behavior is correct as its a density plot. Check the link Gopala provided and check also further questions about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234523/area-under-a-density-plot-not-equal-to-1. Try to normalise your data.

Comment: I am very appreciate with the suggestion from @Gopala, however it is not really I am looking for, because using ``..scaled..`` will give the maximum number of Y_axis as 100%, but it is not histogram. Any suggestion to normalize my data is more than thankful.