# Is it possible to create a density/frequency ggplot in R that corresponds to discrete values on the x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to create a density plot  of the values (Variable 1) for three areas (Variable 2) under two treatments (V3) at four different "stages" (V4). I'll facet wrap V3, so that's no problem.

What I'm finding problematic is to create a custom density plot of V4 on the x axis, with V1 on the y, and V2 as the fill. I know that won't technically be a density plot, but I think it will look good.

So far I have this, which obviously isn't what I want:

```
ggplot(den, aes(Value, colour=Area, group=Area)) + geom_density()
```

Using this code:

```
structure(list(Area = c("Stung Treng", "Stung Treng", "Cardamom Mountains", 
"Cardamom Mountains", "Phnom Penh", "Phnom Penh", "Stung Treng", 
"Stung Treng", "Cardamom Mountains", "Cardamom Mountains", "Phnom Penh", 
"Phnom Penh", "Stung Treng", "Stung Treng", "Cardamom Mountains", 
"Cardamom Mountains", "Phnom Penh", "Phnom Penh", "Stung Treng", 
"Stung Treng", "Cardamom Mountains", "Cardamom Mountains", "Phnom Penh", 
"Phnom Penh", "Stung Treng", "Stung Treng", "Cardamom Mountains", 
"Cardamom Mountains", "Phnom Penh", "Phnom Penh"), `Control/Treatment` = c("Control", 
"Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", 
"Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", 
"Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", 
"Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", 
"Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment"
), Percent = c("% “0”", "% “0”", "% “0”", "% “0”", 
"% “0”", "% “0”", "% “1”", "% “1”", "% “1”", 
"% “1”", "% “1”", "% “1”", "% “2”", "% “2”", 
"% “2”", "% “2”", "% “2”", "% “2”", "% “3”", 
"% “3”", "% “3”", "% “3”", "% “3”", "% “3”", 
"% “4”", "% “4”", "% “4”", "% “4”", "% “4”", 
"% “4”"), Value = c(4, 4.5, 11.9, 13, 13.7, 8.9, 33.2, 30.5, 
47.3, 41, 42.7, 36.3, 37.3, 30.8, 35.3, 36.2, 32.8, 39, 24.6, 
28.1, 5.4, 9.2, 10.2, 13.1, 0.6, 5.8, 0, 0.6, 0.32, 2.4)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), .Names = c("Area", 
"Control/Treatment", "Percent", "Value"), spec = structure(list(
    cols = structure(list(`﻿Area` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `Control/Treatment` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Percent = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Value = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("﻿Area", "Control/Treatment", 
    "Percent", "Value")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of density plot is to plot data density on y-axis (similar to histogram, the area under the curve = 1 for normalized data). Therefore you cannot plot "value" on y-axis, if you want to make a density plot. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234523/area-under-a-density-plot-not-equal-to-1) to learn more about density plots.

If I understood your question correctly, you are after something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

den <- structure(list(Area = c("Stung Treng", "Stung Treng", "Cardamom Mountains", 
"Cardamom Mountains", "Phnom Penh", "Phnom Penh", "Stung Treng", 
"Stung Treng", "Cardamom Mountains", "Cardamom Mountains", "Phnom Penh", 
"Phnom Penh", "Stung Treng", "Stung Treng", "Cardamom Mountains", 
"Cardamom Mountains", "Phnom Penh", "Phnom Penh", "Stung Treng", 
"Stung Treng", "Cardamom Mountains", "Cardamom Mountains", "Phnom Penh", 
"Phnom Penh", "Stung Treng", "Stung Treng", "Cardamom Mountains", 
"Cardamom Mountains", "Phnom Penh", "Phnom Penh"), `Control/Treatment` = c("Control", 
"Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", 
"Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", 
"Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", 
"Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", 
"Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment", "Control", "Treatment"
), Percent = c("% “0”", "% “0”", "% “0”", "% “0”", 
"% “0”", "% “0”", "% “1”", "% “1”", "% “1”", 
"% “1”", "% “1”", "% “1”", "% “2”", "% “2”", 
"% “2”", "% “2”", "% “2”", "% “2”", "% “3”", 
"% “3”", "% “3”", "% “3”", "% “3”", "% “3”", 
"% “4”", "% “4”", "% “4”", "% “4”", "% “4”", 
"% “4”"), Value = c(4, 4.5, 11.9, 13, 13.7, 8.9, 33.2, 30.5, 
47.3, 41, 42.7, 36.3, 37.3, 30.8, 35.3, 36.2, 32.8, 39, 24.6, 
28.1, 5.4, 9.2, 10.2, 13.1, 0.6, 5.8, 0, 0.6, 0.32, 2.4)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), .Names = c("Area", 
"Control/Treatment", "Percent", "Value"), spec = structure(list(
    cols = structure(list(`Area` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `Control/Treatment` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Percent = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Value = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("Area", "Control/Treatment", 
    "Percent", "Value")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))

den$Percent <- as.numeric(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", den$Percent))
colnames(den)[grep("Control", colnames(den))] <- "Treatment"

ggplot(den, aes(x = Percent, y = Value, fill = Area, color = Area, group = Area)) + 
geom_area(position = "identity", alpha = 0.5) + facet_wrap(~Treatment)
```

[image]
Although in my opinion a simple bar plot would be better to show ranked data:

```
ggplot(den, aes(x = Percent, y = Value, fill = Area)) + geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
facet_wrap(~Treatment)
```

[image]

Or then just a line plot:

```
ggplot(den, aes(x = Percent, y = Value, color = Area)) + geom_line() +
 facet_wrap(~Treatment)
```

If you have replicates, you might want to show your data using points, pointranges or boxplots. Also take a look at response ratios: [good paper, although not open access](http://www.jstor.org/stable/177062?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). Those allow you to get rid of facets and just look at the effects. Response ratios require replicates, though.

PS. For your own shake, please do not use "Control/Treatment" as a column name for a data frame. Although R makes it possible to work with such column names these days, they are a pain to work with. Just simplify: also "control" is a treatment, when you are conducting experiments.

Comment: Thank you for this, Mikko. I know what I wanted wasn't accurate in terms of what density actually is, but what you have done with the faux-density plot is exactly what I was picturing might look best (for the purposes of what I'm trying to show). I'll keep in mind bar plots though, thank you. I'm in two minds about what might be best for my purposes. And thanks for the paper recommendation- I'll have a look at it.